# How does AWS know which instance i´m SSH:ing into?

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns

When I SSH into an Amazon instance without an elastic IP I use the public DNS name that is typically of the form ec2-79-125-100-3.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.

Is that DNS name always resolved into the same IP? I assume not, because otherwise there would be no point in buying elastic IP:s. But then what is then the point of including the IP address in the DNS name?

Also, since the IP that the DNS name resolves into is shared by many instances, how does Amazon know exactly which of those instances I'm ssh:ing into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each instance has it's own ip. Even when it's not elastic, it's temporary, but it's still unique to the instance. You don't have 2 instances with the same ip. Otherwise, as you pointed out, there will be no way to know which server is requested when specifying the ip number.

The advantage of elastic ip is that your instance always has the same ip. Without it, you'll get a new ip number each time you restart the instance. Notice that you don't really "buy" elastic ip. You don't pay for it when it's used, meaning in the normal situation where you have a running instance with the elastic ip assigned to it.

Comment: But I thought EC2 instances are virtualized. Shouldn't there be several VM:s running on the same IP?

Comment: It's virtualized in the sense that each instance doesn't necessarily get its own private machine. But it does get it's own ip number.

Answer (score 0):

`ec2-79-125-100-3.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com` is a name that amazon has given to your instance to make it easier for you to get to it.  They could have chosen any naming scheme, but it looks like they have chosen to include the public IP in the public DNS name.  This is merely a convenience to you, and as the other answer points out, will change on every restart.

The advantage of an elastic IP is that you can map your public DNS name to that IP.  For instance, my company has a static IP that points to an EC2 instance.  When I'm ready to push a new version I start up a new EC2 instance, ssh to it and get it all ready to go and tested with the new software using the Amazon assigned public DNS name.  Then, when I'm ready to cut over, I just point the elastic IP at the new instance and take down the old one.  I don't have to mess with DNS mappings because the DNS name and IP haven't changed at all.  It's just one more level of indirection that makes it a little bit easier.

Comment: So when I restart an instance, the public DNS name will also change?

Comment: Why don't they give each instance a static DNS name, like a GUID?